# is there a equivalent of VB6's ChrB in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I am working on migration of VB6 Application to VB.net.

the VB6 code uses ChrB quite often and I need to know how to convert it into vb.net

has anyone faced any similar issue..?

Regards,
Rasheed

Comment: I can't find any good and correct documentation for the ChrB that you write about. Can you finde some?

Comment: Here is what I was able to find about CharB

Comment: Returns a string containing the specified single byte

Comment: This is not quiet helpful :/ I assume now: I put a byte as input in the ChrB function and get back a string that contains one char that has the same ascii number as the byte value interpreted as an 8-bit integer number. Is this right?

Comment: "The ChrB function in earlier versions of Visual Basic returns a single byte. It is used primarily for converting strings in double-byte character set (DBCS) applications. All strings in Visual Basic and the .NET Framework are in Unicode, and ChrB is no longer supported."  
More information is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET doesn’t support “byte-oriented” string methods. 
VB Migration Partner provides the ChrB6 replacement method, which approximates the original VB6 method’s behavior but isn’t guaranteed to work well in all circumstances. This replacement method is marked as obsolete and methods invocations are flagged with a migration warning.